# projectile minor mode is enabled even though all projectile related is commented in init.el

Tags: init-file, projectile

I did install projectile from melpa and now want to give it try. So I fiddled together this lines to get projectile mode.

```
 (use-package projectile
   :config
   (setq projectile-enable-caching t)
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c p f") 'helm-projectile)
   (projectile-global-mode)
   ) ;; end of use-package
```

I also did "touch ~/.emacs.d/.projectile". Now when I open init.el I have projectile minor mode. Actually whati expected... But when I do

```
;;     (use-package projectile
;;       :config
;;       (setq projectile-enable-caching t)
;;       (global-set-key (kbd "C-c p f") 'helm-projectile)
;;       (projectile-global-mode)
;;       ) ;; end of use-package
```

and start a new emacs instance and open init.el it still has projectile minor mode enabled. Now I wonder why is that? Where may this be configured? There is no other version (other then the installed-by-me elpa version) of projectile installed on my hosting machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) `:disable` prop

```
(use-package projectile
  :disabled t
  ...)
```

because you installed it from melpa, it's loaded automatically even if you comment out the code.

Comment: That seems to be a basic fact to know about the packaging system... Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Now that elpa loads projectile automatically can you point me to the emacs lisp code that enables projectile mode? The projectile manual says i have to either  (projectile-global-mode) or (add-hook 'my-mode-hook 'projectile-on) to enabled it. Is emacs packaging doing this already for me? If so where, please?

Comment: I know that for some packages emacs does this automatically activation. For example, if you go to .emacs.d/elpa you will see the packages installed. In each directory there will be a x-autoloads.el which is the code that's loaded when "activating" the package. For go-mode, for example, there is a `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons "\\.go\\'" 'go-mode))` list to enable it on go files in go-mode-autoloads.el. I don't have projectile installed so probably you will find it there.